# Can the built in spatial mapping of the HoloLens be disabled on a per app basis?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, windows-10, spatial, hololens

I have developed an app which is beyond the scale of spatial mapping and therefore I have not included any spatial mapping into my project, but the HoloLens' built in spatial mapping is causing issues, especially in darkened areas. Is there anyway to disable the onboard mapping?
Thanks

Comment: it's a good question

Comment: Any resolution to this after all this time? I too have an app which I was hoping to be able to adjust the Cameras position programmatically. Figured disabling the Spatial Mapping capabilities might be the best place to start when attempting to manually reposition the player in the world. So far nothing useful has turned up.

Comment: The way to resolve this issue is to manually handle tracking loss by using the event and removing the UI tracking loss element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this from DavidKlineMS on [forums.hololens.com](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2829/can-the-built-in-spatial-mapping-be-disabled-on-a-per-app-basis#latesthttp://):

> The HoloLens is constantly scanning the environment. In examples like you describe (darkened areas), tracking can be impacted. If you are looking to disable the UI that indicates tracking loss, you will need to handle it manually.
>
> The documentation pages on handling tracking loss (Unity and DirectX) may help you here.

Answer (score 2):

That capability is not currently available in any of the exposed API's.  I would suggest asking the same question in forums.hololens.com and see if you can get the attention of someone from Microsoft as a requested feature.

Comment: Yeah, I had read through the API docs, just hoped someone here had a solution. I have it posted in the hololens forum, but so far its up for a day and has 13 views, but no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be disabled.

There used to be a function called `SetMappingEnabled`. I think that Microsoft removed this function after some update. You could simply call  `SpatialMappingManager.Instance.SetMappingEnabled(false)` but not anymore.

```
SpatialMappingManager.Instance.DrawVisualMeshes = false;
```

should be able to disable Spatial. I would disable Spatial shadow too. Use the function below to disable Spatial.

```
void disableSpatialMapping()
{
    SpatialMappingManager.Instance.StopObserver();
    SpatialMappingManager.Instance.CastShadows = false;
    SpatialMappingManager.Instance.DrawVisualMeshes = false;
}
```

Comment: He stated he did not include Spatial Mapping in the project, so he would not have a SpatialMappingManager...

Comment: I just got into the office now and although skeptical, tested your solution anyway and as stated by @CameronVetter, this does not work as I do not have the spatial mapping manger class. Adding it will not disable the built in Spatial Mapping sensors of the actual device, it would just disable the app's spatial functionality.

Comment: Actually `SpatialMappingManager` comes with the Halolens SDK "HoloToolkit-Unity" when that is installed. Unless I am missing something, "HoloToolkit-Unity" should be installed when building from Unity. Both you and @CameronVetter are mentioning `SpatialMappingManager` as if that is the only thing that comes with the SDK. It has other classes for sound, input and more. So when you said "I have not included any spatial mapping into my project", I thought you meant that you have not used the `SpatialMappingManager` class in your project. Is this what you meant or did you not install the SDK?

Comment: I have all the required SDK's and have built apps using the managers, this particular app does not include the spatialmapping class as I do not need any mapping in this current project.

Comment: @CameronVetter Has anyone tried including the SpatialMappingManager/Observer scripts into their scene and then running the code?